# jQuery validation engine won't work with jQuery 1.8+

Tags: javascript, jquery

I updated `jQuery 1.8.3` to latest version and jQuery validation engine stopped working. I tested it with 1.8.3+ (any version) but it doesn't work.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#source").select2({
        closeOnSelect: false,
        formatResult: format,
        formatSelection: format,
        blurOnChange: true
    });
    $('#testform').validationEngine({ prettySelect: true, usePrefix: 's2id_', autoPositionUpdate: true });
});


function format(state) {
    // Update: Made it work by changing "state.element" to $(state.element). 
    var originalOption = $(state.element);
    return originalOption.data('foo') + " " + state.text;
}
```

How do I fix this ?

Demo in [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BbDpH/56/)  (changed to jQuery 1.8.3) validation worked.

Comment: Replace instances of `.live(` with `.on(`. You should learn how to debug js errors: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code

Comment: you can either try to update the validate engine version, or use the jQuery migration plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the usage of [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method in validate engine 2.6 which was [removed in jQuery 1.9](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#live-removed).

You can update the validate engine to [2.6.2](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-Validation-Engine/2.6.2/jquery.validationEngine.js) or [latest](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-Validation-Engine/2.6.4/jquery.validationEngine.js) where it is fixed by using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)